# Word Styles to get two elements to share same background/border

Tags: ms-word, word-2010

Within MS Word 2013 I am trying to create a text element plus a list underneath it, all wrapped inside a coloured border with background shading (see image).  The attached image shows the text in plain form.

I would like to place a blue border around *both* the title *and* the list.  I can achieve this by placing both objects within a 1x1 table and applying colouring rules to the cell, but semantically this seems bad (I'm from an HTML development background where it is **very** wrong!)

When I edit a Style rule to create the border/background, it works well until I create the list, then it goes badly wrong.  Is it possible to achieve the output of the table cell approach by only using a style rule and no table?

[image: Good styles and bad styles!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of experimentation, the closest I can get is by doing the following:

1. Create a style rule called **Tips Heading** based on **Normal**, then set it to be Bold with a blue background.
2. Create another style rule called **Tips List** based on **List Paragraph**, and set it to have a blue background.

Unfortunately the List cannot be indented because the background colour also indents.  The border is also affected in this manner, so I ignored the border and indentation.  It works really well and is semantically well structured.